# Converting NSStrings to C chars and calling a C function from Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, nsstring

I'm in an Objective-C method with various `NSString`s that I want to pass to a C function.  The C function requires a `struct` object be `malloc`'d so that it can be passed in - this struct contains `char` fields.  So the `struct` is defined like this:

```
struct libannotate_baseManual {
    char *la_bm_code;  // The base code for this manual (pointer to malloc'd memory)
    char *la_bm_effectiveRevisionId; // The currently effective revision ID (pointer to malloc'd memory or null if none effective)
    char **la_bm_revisionId; // The null-terminated list of revision IDs in the library for this manual (pointer to malloc'd array of pointers to malloc'd memory)
};
```

This struct is then used in the following C function definition:

```
void libannotate_setManualLibrary(struct libannotate_baseManual **library) { ..
```

So that's the function I need to call from Objective-C.

So I have various `NSString`s that I basically want to pass in there, to represent the chars - `la_bm_code`, `la_bm_effectiveRevisionId`, `la_bm_revision`.  I could convert those to `const char`s by using `[NSString UTF8String]`, but I need `char`s, not `const char`s.

Also I need to do suitable `malloc`'s for these fields, though apparently I don't need to worry about freeing the memory afterwards.  C is not my strong point, though I know Objective-C well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strdup()` is your friend here as that both `malloc()`s and `strcpy()`s for you in one simple step.  It's memory is also released using `free()` and it does your `const char *` to `char *` conversion for you!

```
NSString *code = ..., *effectiveRevId = ..., *revId = ...;
struct libannotate_baseManual *abm = malloc(sizeof(struct libannotate_baseManual));
abm->la_bm_code = strdup([code UTF8String]);
abm->la_bm_effectiveRevisionId = strdup([effectiveRevId UTF8String]);
const unsigned numRevIds = 1;
abm->la_bm_effectiveRevisionId = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (numRevIds + 1));
abm->la_bm_effectiveRevisionId[0] = strdup([revId UTF8String]);
abm->la_bm_effectiveRevisionId[1] = NULL;

const unsigned numAbms = 1;    
struct libannotate_baseManual **abms = malloc(sizeof(struct libannotate_baseManual *) * (numAbms + 1));
abms[0] = abm;
abms[1] = NULL;
libannotate_setManualLibrary(abms);
```

Good luck, you'll need it.  It's one of the worst interfaces I've ever seen.

Comment: That is fantastic, thanks.  Trying now.  BTW yes - need to pass in an array of pointers, so looking at that also.